# What's the Best Way to Handle Data Entry Errors Inside Property Let in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

in the **Property Let** in a *ModelClass*, I'd like to know what's the best way to advice the client class *(ViewClass)* about each data entry error.

please, find the **ModelClass** sample code, as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private m_idCompra As String

Public Property Get codCompra() As String
    codCompra = m_idCompra
End Property

Public Property Let codCompra(ByVal codigoCompra As String)
    'Data entry roughly treated, just to illustrate.
    If Len(codigoCompra) = 0 Then
        'Advice ViewClass somehow
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(codigoCompra) Then
        'Advice ViewClass somehow
    'Elseif...
    
    Else
        m_idCompra = codigoCompra
        'Advice ViewClass somehow
    End If
End Property
```

*m_idCompra* must be **String** type, in this case.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How often might the user provide incorrect data? Can the programme continue even with an incorrect value? You can raise an exception in VBA using `Err.Raise`, and let the user handle it (or not).

Comment: @DS_London for the moment, the input will be limited to 0-9 keys but later it might also receive copy-paste inputs then it will be necessary to check if the input data is empty, if it is @&%/... if it is over 13 digits, and for each wrong data, I need to advice the client in order to take the due actions. in what case do you use **custom events** with `WithEvents`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For similar cases, I add *methods* like:

```vb
Public Function SetCompra(ByVal codigoCompra As String) As Boolean

    Dim Valid As Boolean

    Valid = IsValidCompra(codigoCompra)
    If Valid Then
        ' Set property.
        m_idCompra = codigoCompra
    Else
        ' Raise error or pop message box.
    End If

    SetCompra = Valid

End Function


Public Function IsValidCompra(ByVal codigoCompra As String) As Boolean

    Dim Valid As Boolean

    If <your validation rules> = True Then
        Valid = True
    End If

    IsValidCompra = Valid

End Function
```

Comment: I had the same idea but I was trying to avoid it due to the fact that I was not going to use `Property Let` to do the data entry. I just needed to hear from the experts what's the best way to do that and your answer shows the best way. one question: in what case do you use **custom events** with `WithEvents`?

Comment: That I only do when having _many_ similar controls. One example is here: [Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html?preview=yawJg2wkMzc%3D)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to continue to use Property Let, but add an Enum of error codes to your class to let the user determine what action to take if an error is raised:

eg **MySimpleClass** module:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_strId As String

Public Enum MSC_Errors
    'MS uses this offset to avoid in-built automation error codes AFAIK
    MSC_ID_EMPTY = vbObjectError + 513
    MSC_ID_NOTNUMBER
End Enum

Public Property Get Id() As String
    Id = m_strId
End Property

Public Property Let Id(ByVal sNewVal As String)
    If Len(sNewVal) = 0 Then
        Err.Raise MSC_Errors.MSC_ID_EMPTY, Description:="Id cannot be empty string"
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(sNewVal) Then
        Err.Raise MSC_Errors.MSC_ID_NOTNUMBER, Description:="Id must be a number"
    End If
    
    m_strId = sNewVal
End Property
```

Then as an example of client code:

```
Sub TestId()
    Dim myobj As New MySimpleClass
    
    On Error GoTo IdError
    
    myobj.Id = InputBox("Enter a numeric Id", "Id Entry")
    
    MsgBox "Good Id=" & myobj.Id
    
    Exit Sub
    
IdError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    TestId
End Sub
```

The client can go further and query the Error code that you have provided, eg:

```
If Err.Number = MSC_Errors.MSC_ID_EMPTY Then
    'Assign a default id    
    myobj.Id=42
End If
```

Of course, this a somewhat contrived example, but it gives a way to communicate the reason for the error to the client code.